# Which is better <link rel="prefetch" vs script defer?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been using defer attribute with script tags but just found out about the <link rel="prefetch" as="script" is a thing but can not find which is better or preferred? And what is the difference between these methods?

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="library.js" as="script">
```

vs

```
<script defer="" src="library.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're two very different things. `<link rel="prefetch">` indicates to the browser that some resource (not necessarily JavaScript) is going to be needed. This is useful if you're loading resources dynamically via JavaScript.

`<script defer>` alters when the JavaScript code is *executed*. It is fetched as soon as the browser encounters the element, but it is only run when the document is fully loaded.

They can be similar in these cases:

- `<link rel="prefetch">` in the `<head>` and `<script>` in the end of the `<body>`
- `<script defer>` in the `<head>`

In both cases, the JavaScript resource is fetched at the same time but in the first example, the JavaScript is executed just before the whole `<body>` is loaded, while in the second, the JavaScript is executed after the whole document is loaded (i.e. all the elements are in the DOM).

---

About which is better: I would use `<script defer>` in the `<head>` instead because:

- It doesn't block the HTML parser,
- It has better compatibility and
- Less stuff to write.

Comment: `In both cases, the JavaScript resource is fetched at the same time` loading resources with `prefetch` has a lower priority then for `defer`, so it is likely that the script won’t be loaded before the `script` tag is reach for the `link` `script` combination. And there likely won’t be a difference if the `link` tag exists in that case or not.

Answer (score 6):

`defer` on a `script` will load and execute the script.

A `link` with `prefetch` will instruct the browser to load a resource with low priority, but it won’t do anything else with it except caching.

So if you you want to load and execute a script you need to use a `script` tag. If you want that the browser loads a script because it might be needed in the near future but you don’t want to execute it yet you use `prefetch`